# Remove character from databinder in repeater C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

n an ascx file I'm presenting data from a databound field like this:

```
<%# Eval("Description")%>
```

The data source is bound from code behind.

Sometimes Description has some characters in it that I need to replace. I would love if I could just do something like this:

```
<%# Replace(Eval("Description"), "a", "b")%>
```

But of course that's not allowed in a databind operation (<%#).

I don't want to hard code it in code behind because it would be so ugly to extract the field in code behind, maybe extract it to a variable and then output the variable on the ascx page. I'm hoping there is some (probably really easy) way I can do the replace directly on the ascx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%# ((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")).Replace("a", "b") %>
```

user above syntax